# How do I unlock the bootloader on an LG K120 (K4 LTE 2016)?

Tags: lg, bootloader-lock

I got a used LG K4 off eBay and I'm looking to flash a Marshmallow ROM. I tried downloading the SuperSu ZIP file and booting into recovery, but the only option was factory reset.

I rebooted and tried Kingroot, because you don't need to boot into recovery for it to work. It didn't work, it just said 'Root failed'.

I did some research and found out that you need to unlock the bootloader. I didn't know this because on my previous phone the bootloader was already unlocked. I searched on how to unlock it on my device but all the suggestions just told me to boot into recovery.

Is there a good way to manually unlock the bootloader? I have a raspberry pi 3 and my mother has a Windows 10 laptop, so either can work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

LG has agreed to provide bootloader unlocks for a certain few models. Here is [the official LG site for unlocking bootloader](https://developer.lge.com/resource/mobile/RetrieveBootloader.dev).

Comment: It's best to provide a summary in your answer, so people know what to expect (is the link to instructions, a download, a registration form, or something else).

Comment: According to the "Supported Devices", No "K" series is supported for unlocking the bootloader.